# android: database crashes my app.

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i recently added a third table to my database which i am using to do a quiz app. when i try to use the third table for the quiz it crashes the app. i'm pretty sure the problem is in my DBhelper but i'm not sure where as i looked through the whole class.

DBHelper class

```
public class DBHelper extends  SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "triviaQuiz";
// tasks table name
private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
private static final String TABLE_QUEST2 = "quest2";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID2 = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES2 = "question"; 
private static final String TABLE_QUEST3 = "quest3";
// tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID3 = "id";
private static final String KEY_QUES3 = "question";
private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
dbase=db;
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
+ " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
+KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql);
addQuestions();
String sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST2 + " ( "
        + KEY_ID2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES2
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
        +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql2);
addQuestions2();
String sql3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST3 + " ( "
        + KEY_ID3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES3
        + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER+ " TEXT, "+KEY_OPTA +" TEXT, "
        +KEY_OPTB +" TEXT, "+KEY_OPTC+" TEXT)";
db.execSQL(sql3);
addQuestions3();
//db.close();
}

private void addQuestions()
{
    Question q1=new Question("8 X 2 " + "=","16", "20", "18", "16");
    this.addQuestion(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("8 X 3  " +    "=", "20", "24", "26", "24");
    this.addQuestion(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("8 X 4 " + " =","30", "35","32","32");
    this.addQuestion(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("8 X 5 " + " = ", "40", "38", "41","40");
    this.addQuestion(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("8 X 6 " +" =","45","48","50","48");
    this.addQuestion(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("8 X 7 " +" =","55","56","58","56");
    this.addQuestion(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("8 X 8 " +" =","64","68","60","64");
    this.addQuestion(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("8 X 9 " +" =","75","72","70","72");
    this.addQuestion(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("8 X 10 " +" =","81","89","80","80");
    this.addQuestion(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("8 X [  ]  " +" = 8","1","9","5","1");
    this.addQuestion(q10);
    Question q11=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 24","5","3","6","3");
    this.addQuestion(q11);
    Question q12=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 40","6","9","5","5");
    this.addQuestion(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 56","7","8","9","7");
    this.addQuestion(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("8 X [  ] " +" = 80","7","10","9","10");
    this.addQuestion(q14);
}
private void addQuestions2()
{
    Question q1=new Question("2 X 2 " + "=","4", "2", "6", "4");
    this.addQuestion2(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("2 X 3  " +    "=", "7", "6", "5", "6");
    this.addQuestion2(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("2 X 4 " + " =","9", "10","8","8");
    this.addQuestion2(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("2 X 5 " + " = ", "8", "10", "9","10");
    this.addQuestion2(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("2 X 6 " +" =","12","13","11","12");
    this.addQuestion2(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("2 X 7 " +" =","13","14","15","14");
    this.addQuestion2(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("2 X 8 " +" =","16","14","15","16");
    this.addQuestion2(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("2 X 9 " +" =","17","19","18","18");
    this.addQuestion2(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("2 X 10 " +" =","21","19","20","20");
    this.addQuestion2(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("2 X [  ]  " +" = 8","1","4","5","4");
    this.addQuestion2(q10);
    Question q11=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 4","2","3","6","2");
    this.addQuestion2(q11);
    Question q12=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 10","6","9","5","5");
    this.addQuestion2(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 14","7","8","9","7");
    this.addQuestion2(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("2 X [  ] " +" = 20","7","10","9","10");
    this.addQuestion2(q14);
}
private void addQuestions3()
{
    Question q1=new Question("2 X 2 " + "=","4", "2", "6", "4");
    this.addQuestion2(q1);
    Question q2=new Question("2 X 3  " +    "=", "7", "6", "5", "6");
    this.addQuestion2(q2);
    Question q3=new Question("2 X 4 " + " =","9", "10","8","8");
    this.addQuestion2(q3);
    Question q4=new Question("2 X 5 " + " = ", "8", "10", "9","10");
    this.addQuestion2(q4);
    Question q5=new Question("2 X 6 " +" =","12","13","11","12");
    this.addQuestion2(q5);
    Question q6=new Question("2 X 7 " +" =","13","14","15","14");
    this.addQuestion2(q6);
    Question q7=new Question("2 X 8 " +" =","16","14","15","16");
    this.addQuestion2(q7);
    Question q8=new Question("2 X 9 " +" =","17","19","18","18");
    this.addQuestion2(q8);
    Question q9=new Question("2 X 10 " +" =","21","19","20","20");
    this.addQuestion2(q9);
    Question q10=new Question("8 X 2 " +    "=","16", "20", "18", "16");
    this.addQuestion(q10);
    Question q12=new Question("8 X 3  " +   "=", "20", "24", "26", "24");
    this.addQuestion(q12);
    Question q13=new Question("8 X 4 " +    " =","30", "35","32","32");
    this.addQuestion(q13);
    Question q14=new Question("8 X 5 " +    " = ", "40", "38", "41","40");
    this.addQuestion(q14);
    Question q15=new Question("8 X 6 " +" =","45","48","50","48");
    this.addQuestion(q15);
    Question q16=new Question("8 X 7 " +" =","55","56","58","56");
    this.addQuestion(q16);
    Question q17=new Question("8 X 8 " +" =","64","68","60","64");
    this.addQuestion(q17);
    Question q18=new Question("8 X 9 " +" =","75","72","70","72");
    this.addQuestion(q18);
    Question q19=new Question("8 X 10 " +" =","81","89","80","80");
    this.addQuestion(q19);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
onCreate(db);
}
// Adding new question
public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
//SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
// Inserting Row
dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
}
public void addQuestion2(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES2, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST2, null, values);
    }
public void addQuestion3(Question quest) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_QUES3, quest.getQUESTION());
    values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
    values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
    values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
    values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
    // Inserting Row
    dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST3, null, values);
    }
public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Question quest = new Question();
quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
quesList.add(quest);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
// return quest list
return quesList;
}
public List<Question> getAllQuestions2() {
List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST2;
dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
do {
Question quest = new Question();
quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
quesList.add(quest);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
}

// return quest list
return quesList;
}
public List<Question> getAllQuestions3() {
    List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST3;
    dbase=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    Question quest = new Question();
    quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
    quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
    quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
    quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
    quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
    quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
    quesList.add(quest);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return quest list
    return quesList;
    }

public int rowcount()
{
int row=0;
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
row=cursor.getCount();
return row;
}
}
```

here is the class that calls the third table

```
public class Combine extends Activity 
{
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int rand1 = randomGenerator.nextInt(18);
int rand2;
List<Question> quesList;
int score=0;
int qid=0;
Question currentQ;
TextView txtQuestion;
Button rda, rdb, rdc;
Button butNext;
MediaPlayer mysound;
boolean loaded=false;
private SoundPool soundPool,soundPool2;
int soundID, soundID2;
private Chronometer chrono;
int timer =60;
String count = "01:00";
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_combine);
    DBHelper db=new DBHelper(this);
    quesList=db.getAllQuestions3();
    currentQ=quesList.get(rand1);
    txtQuestion=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    rda=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio0);
    rdb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rdc=(Button)findViewById(R.id.radio2);
    rda.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    rdb.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    rdc.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

    this.chrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.calling_crono);
    startCrono();
    //butNext=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    setQuestionView();
    chrono.setOnChronometerTickListener(new OnChronometerTickListener() {

        public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) 
        {
            String currentTime= chrono.getText().toString();
            timer --;
            count = "00:"+timer;

            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").parse(currentTime);
            }catch (java.text.ParseException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String newTime = new SimpleDateFormat("mm:ss").format(date);
            if(newTime.equals("01:00")) 
            {
                chrono.stop();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Combine.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                int end = -5;
                b.putInt("score", score);
                b.putInt("end", end);
                intent.putExtras(b); 
                soundPool.release();
                soundPool2.release();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
             }
        }
    });
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
           @Override
           public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                   int status) {
               loaded = true;
           }
       });
       soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.correct, 1);
       soundPool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

       soundPool2.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
              @Override
              public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                      int status) {
                  loaded = true;
              }
          });

          soundID2 = soundPool2.load(this, R.raw.error, 1);

}
private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int rand2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(18);
        TextView answer = (TextView) v;
        if(currentQ.getANSWER().equals(answer.getText()))
        {
            score++;
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                      .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
            soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
            Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }
        else
        {
            AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
            float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                          .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
            .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

                soundPool2.play(soundID2, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
        }
        currentQ=quesList.get(rand2);
        setQuestionView();
    }
};
public void startCrono() {
     chrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
     chrono.start();
    }
private void setQuestionView()
{
    txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
    rda.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
    rdb.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
    rdc.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
    qid++;
}


}
```

logcat for those that need it

```
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.timestableseasy.Combine}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 0
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:150)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1298)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5225)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:741)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 16, size is 0
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at com.example.timestableseasy.Combine.onCreate(Combine.java:54)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-17 14:30:01.238: E/AndroidRuntime(10699):    ... 11 more
```

line 54 that the log cat points out is

> quesList=db.getAllQuestions3();
>           currentQ=quesList.get(rand1);

Comment: the error seems pretty clear as to the problem, the size is 0 and you are trying to get something at index 16 with a list of size 0

Comment: @tyczj but then why is that happening as i have 19 questions being put into the table i'm using so in theory it should have more than 16 things in it

Comment: The evidence shows that your table does not contain 19 questions.

Comment: @CL ok i get that but looking at the DBHelper and going through the DBHelper code shows that the third table "quest3" has 19 questions. is there something that has stopped there from being 19 questions?

Comment: then either your query is not right or you really dont have what you think you do in the table

Comment: Did you ever have an in-development version of this app that did not fill the `quest3` table?

Comment: @CL no when i added in the table i added in the question. though it has be pointed out that my third table is not getting questions added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addQuestion3()` method is not adding anything to the third table. It's adding to the second and first tables. So when you're querying the third table with `getAllQuestions3()` it's returning an empty list, since there are no entries in the third table.

Comment: wait why is it not adding questions? i thought that if i called it after the string i create the table then it should work

Comment: Look at the methods you're calling in that method. You're using the methods to add the questions to table one and two. `this.addQuestion2(q1);`